# Which is more efficient in Erlang: match on two different lines, or match in tuple?

Tags: performance, coding-style, erlang, pattern-matching, record

Which of these two is more efficient in Erlang? This:

```
ValueA = MyRecord#my_record.value_a,
ValueB = MyRecord#my_record.value_b.
```

Or this:

```
{ValueA, ValueB} = {MyRecord#my_record.value_a, MyRecord#my_record.value_b}.
```

?

I ask because the latter sometimes brings me to need multiple lines to fit in the 80 character line length limit I like to keep, and I tend to prefer to avoid doing stuff like this:

```
{ValueA, ValueB} = { MyRecord#my_record.value_a
                   , MyRecord#my_record.value_b }.
```

Comment: Although knowing which one is faster is an interesting information, the difference is probably so small that you should favor maintainability over performance. The question should be: "which one looks better?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They generate exactly the same code! If you want less code try using:

```
#my_record{value_a=ValueA,value_b=ValueB} = MyRecord
```

which also generates the same code. Generally, if you can, use pattern matching. It is never worse, usually better. In this case they all do the minimum amount of work which is necessary.

In general write the code which is clearest and looks the best and only worry about these types of optimisation when you **know** that there is a speed problem with this code.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a little test, and it seems they are roughly equivalent:

```
-module(timeit).
-export([test/0]).

-record(my_record, {value_a, value_b}).

times(N, Fn) ->
    fun () -> do_times(N, Fn) end.

do_times(0, _Fn) ->
    ok;
do_times(N, Fn) ->
    Fn(),
    do_times(N-1, Fn).

test_1() ->
    MyRecord = #my_record{value_a=1, value_b=2},
    timer:tc(times(100000000,
       fun () ->
           ValueA = MyRecord#my_record.value_a,
           ValueB = MyRecord#my_record.value_b,
           ValueA + ValueB
       end)).

test_2() ->
    MyRecord = #my_record{value_a=1, value_b=2},
    timer:tc(times(100000000,
       fun () ->
           {ValueA, ValueB} = { MyRecord#my_record.value_a,
                                MyRecord#my_record.value_b },
           ValueA + ValueB
       end)).

test() ->
    {test_1(), test_2()}.

44> timeit:test().
{{6042747,ok},{6063557,ok}}
45> timeit:test().
{{5849173,ok},{5822836,ok}}
46>
```

Btw, I had to add the "ValueA + ValueB" expression so the compiler doesn't treat the ValueA binding in test_1 as dead code. If you remove it, you'll see a big difference in the times because of that.